# Visual Studio "New Item" not showing all options

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsconfig

I have started a **Cordova project** with **Visual Studio 2015**. I don't know if this is standard behavior, but when I right click to add a new item, I get only few options. I wanted to add i.e "TypeScript json config file" aka `tsconfig`, but I don't get this option and I also fell like other many options are missing. This is a new computer and I don't know if I'm missing any kind of installation.

[image]

Comment: I have the same items like you, so I think it is standard behavior, we should add tsconfig manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options in the Add New Item dialog are different for Cordova projects, versus other projects like ASP.NET. The list you see here is what you get with Cordova projects. That being said - I'll forward this feedback along to our team (I'm part of the Visual Studio Cordova Tools team)!